# Canvas - Chrome and Firefox display small ctx.lineWidth differently

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am using a small value (0.06) for ctx.lineWidth in my canvas design, and I noticed that Chrome (and also Edge) displays the result differently than Firefox (System: Windows 10). My desired output is Firefox version, which looks grainy. You can see the difference below (left: Firefox, right: Chrome):

[image]

Is there any remedy to this issue?

Here's my code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var cw = canvas.width = canvas.height = Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'; ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cw, cw);
var u = cw / 1000;
var cx = 500 * u, cy = 500 * u;
var colorsP = [['304B5D','B48B35'],['3B999F','E5C91C'],['854B68','B9602B'],['AF1D16','779C3C'],['9E4EB3','F1D628'],['6B2142','DF748A'],['663388','AA6600'],['BBDFD5','E9D038'],['304350','D9B15C'],['99BC44','274140'],['4A122F','90181A'],['184299','24B885'],['B84224','D28928'],['CD4316','E5D03C'],['826071','D77D48'],['DF7D36','5065A8'],['B0244B','D39639'],['CE2C14','91A86D'],['A16DAF','D1C578'],['42408C','D4455E'],['481F31','F28FA3'],['334E94','7C85B0'],['1C3982','4175AC']];

var colors = randomItem(colorsP);
colors.push('FFFFFF','000000','000000');

// Origins
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    let color = colors[randomNumber(0, colors.length - 1)];
    
    // Points
    let points = [];
    for (let j = 1; j <= 60; j++) {
        let x = j * j * randomNumber(240, 860) * u;
        let y = j * j * randomNumber(240, 860) * u;
        points.push([x,y]);
    }
    
    // Rotations
    for (let j = 1; j <= 200; j++) {
        ctx.beginPath(); ctx.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]); for (let k = 1; k < points.length; k++) ctx.lineTo(points[k][0], points[k][1]); ctx.lineWidth = 0.06; ctx.strokeStyle = '#'+color; ctx.stroke();
        ctx.translate(cx, cy); ctx.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI / 180); ctx.translate(-cx, -cy);
    }
}

function randomItem(arr) { return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]; }
function randomNumber(min, max) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've got the same result on FF, Chrome and Safari (on macOS) even while forcing software rendering, and it's the one on the right. Not sure where the noise comes from for the one on the left... If it's what you want, the best is probably to make your code do it explicitly, e.g in https://jsfiddle.net/kwep9amf/ we composite the result with some white noise to get a "similar" result. But it would be quite important to find out what happens in your Firefox, since that might just *add-up* and still not produce the same result. So which exact version of FF do you see this in?

Comment: I wonder if this is affected by zoom level? Also, what OS is this?

Comment: @Kaiido I'm on Windows 10, Firefox 101.0.1 (64 bit). Someone told me that it is something to do with how Chrome (and some other browsers) handles very thin line strokes (0.06 in my case). If you are seeing the same right version on all browsers on Mac, then I guess that must be the expected output (I can't tell for sure), and my Firefox output was an anomaly. Thanks for the manual grain suggestion, I added it before seeing your comment actually. Still, I wish the default output was how I see it in my Firefox...